# Retrofit Unexpected end of stream Connection

Tags: android, .net, connection, retrofit

I'm currently trying to connect my android application to a local ASP.NET backend.
While doing so, I keep getting the error
`Retrofit Unexpected end of stream Connection`

I really have no clue where I'm wrong. I looked at other solutions, but none of those seem to help me.
I've read something about the content length being the issue. In my Startup.cs's configure method, I've noticed the following piece of code.

```cs
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DataInitializer dataInitializer)
        {
            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
                {
                    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                }
            });
```

However I have no idea if this is the cause of my issue.

Below I've added the rest of the code which might be part of the problem.

**Startup.cs of .Net**

```cs
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            //AddScopeds for each repository//
            //...//
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowCredentials();
        }));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(cfg => cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddOpenApiDocument(
   c =>
   {
       c.DocumentName = "apidocs";
       c.Title = "Test API";
       c.Version = "v1";
       c.Description = "The Test API documentation description.";
       c.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("JWT Token", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
       {
           Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
           Name = "Authorization",
           In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
           Description = "Copy 'Bearer' + valid JWT token into field"
       }));
       c.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT Token"));
   }
);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true //Ensure token hasn't expired
                };
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, KlimaatMobielDataInitializer dataInitializer)
        {
            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
                {
                    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                }
            });
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins"); //
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", @"Resources")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/Resources")
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
```

**Retrofit interface**

```
private const val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:5001/api/"
    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()

    interface TestApiService {
        @GET("material")
        fun getMaterials():
                Call<List<Material>>
    }

    object TestApi {
        val retrofitService: KlimaatApiService by lazy {
            retrofit.create(KlimaatApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
```

**Using the interface**

```
    public fun getMaterialen() {
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        KlimaatApi.retrofitService.getMaterialen().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Material>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Material>>, t: Throwable) {
                _response.value = "Failure: " + t.message
                Timber.e(t.message)
            }
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Material>>,
                response: Response<List<Material>>
            ) {

                if(!response.isSuccessful){

                    Timber.e("Code: ${response.code()}")
                }
                var materials = response.body()
                for(mat in materials!!){
                    Timber.e(mat.name)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```